# Nested lists in rows - CSS

Tags: html, css, list, navigation

I'm trying to create a navigation menu. I'd like the sub-menus to be shown as rows under their parent list item, like this (block version!):

Diagram of desired result:

[image]

The problem is I'm struggling to display them as such.

I've put together a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/

As you can see, it lists all the `li`s in order, but I'd like the sub-list of `list item 2` to be displayed as a row under the first 4 `list item`s.

Is this possible?
If so, any pointers?

### [EDIT]

To help explain the end result, here is another image of the eventual stages I will create.

Diagram of end result:

[image]

As you can see, I'd like to just layout the lists, then I'll use jQuery to show/hide via a sliding animation the sublists etc...

I hope that helps explain what I'm eventually trying to achieve.

### [EDIT 2]

I've got a little further. I've added some more list items to try and make this more scalable.

I've basically given the top row a bottom margin to push it down and made the sub-list absolutely positioned.

Where I'm stuck now is if the first sublist is 2 rows deep.

I plan to then use jQuery to show/hide the sublists.

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/20/

Comment: what happens if 2 items in one row both have sublists or the sublists go over more than one line?

Comment: The navigation is for wordpress theme on a tablet device, I will in the end be using jQuery to show the sub lists on tap. Right now I'm just trying to work out how to display all the items as I've shown in the image.

Comment: I think any solution would require there to be a fixed number of items in each level of list...is this acceptable?

Comment: It's a good point Paulie, I'm now trying to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

```
#main-list ul li{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
 }
 #sub-list-1,
 #sub-list-2{border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 157px;
    z-index: 1;display:none;cursor:pointer;}
  #sub-list-1 li,
  #sub-list-2 li{
   float:none;    
}
#main-list li:hover + #sub-list-1,
#main-list li:hover + #sub-list-2{
     display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't however need the hover states at the moment, I'm just trying to layout the lists in the way shown in my image.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give you two ways of solving this(there are many more).

Example 1: You can add a 100% width to your sub-menu and left float it which will cause it to be pushed down to it's own row.

[Ex 1 FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/10/)

`#main-list ul {float: left; width: 100%; padding: 0px;}`

Example 2: You can clear all floats around the sub-menu causing it to be pushed down to it's own row.

[Ex 2 FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/17/)

```
#main-list ul + li{clear: both;}
#main-list ul {clear: both; padding: 0px;}
```

**EDIT**

Like the asker mentioned in the comments below the previous sollution breaks the grid.
I made a quick javascript sollution that dynamically changes the height of the margin pushing down the elements below. 
To determine which row to add the margin to I get the index of the item and check if it's between 0-3(first four elements) if not I add +4(4-7) and check again...

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/25/)

To make this possible I somewhat changed the HTML structure by placing the sub-menu inside of it's parent LI like so:

```
<li>list item 2
    <ul id="sub-list-1" class="sub-list">
         <li>Sub list item 1</li>
         <li>Sub list item 2</li>
         <li>Sub list item 3</li>
         <li>Sub list item 4</li>
         <li>Sub list item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

**The jquery**

```
$("#main-list > li").click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
        if($(this).children("ul")){
            $(this).removeClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
            $(this).css("margin-bottom", "0px").siblings().css("margin-bottom", "0px");
            var menuPosition = $(this).index();

            var sublist = $(this).find("ul");
            var sublistHeight = sublist.height();
            var menuPosition = $(this).index();
            var startNumber = 0;
            var stopNumber = 3;

            while(stopNumber <= $("#main-list > li").size()-1){
                if(startNumber <= menuPosition && menuPosition <= stopNumber){
                    for (var i = startNumber; i <= stopNumber; i++) {
                        $("#main-list > li").eq(i).css("margin-bottom", sublistHeight);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    startNumber += 4;
                    stopNumber += 4;
                }
            }

            //$(this).css("margin-bottom", sublistHeight).siblings().css("margin-bottom", sublistHeight);
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    }
    else{
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(this).css("margin-bottom", "0px").siblings().css("margin-bottom", "0px");
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies Natalie. But both of these break the grid i.e. list item number 4 is placed under the sub list. I've got a little further here. I'm just trying to get it to work with a 5th sub list item http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/20/

Comment: ah yes of course. Since you said you were gonna use jquery to hide/show the sub-menus I made this quick-fix for the issue. There's still work that needs to be done on it of course.   [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/21/)

Comment: @Steviehype I improved the fiddle a bit [http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/24/](http://jsfiddle.net/8skzF/24/)

Comment: Wow, thanks for all your work! Much appreciated Natalie.

Comment: NP, glad to be a help. I addded this sollution to my original answer, so if it helped you would you mind accepting this as an answer?